# AJAX: Display value from table in datase with <select> tag (incomplete submit)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with my code.. when I'm submitting value of the  in getinv.php it is submitting incomplete value for example, when I click '2016-08-27' it only returning '2016'..

My question is, How do I submit this with exact value I want..?

Pls. Help!

Here's my code:

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showProd(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getinv.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>



<form>
<select name="date" onchange="showProd(this.value)">
<option value="">Select date here:</option>
 
 <?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','posinventory');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT DATE FROM inventory WHERE DATE != DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY DATE DESC;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</option>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>


</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getinv.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
echo $q;
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','posinventory');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE DATE = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>tran_num</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>item_num</th>
<th>inv_quan</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B8Eg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the date is being submitted correctly. Inside getinv.php, you are using [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), which returns the integer value from date and since date starts with a digit, it returns all digits up to but excluding the first dash, so '2016-08-27' becomes '2016'.

Replace

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

with

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```